# Ruby TCPServer not listening to port on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform

I got a school assignment that asks us to practice some socket programming, so my plan is running my backend on the VM provided by Google Cloud Platform and sending some message from my local computer to it. 
But when I running the client-side code it says connection refused. Later checked with `netstat -a` on the cloud shell and it says my program is not even listening (while it's running in background).

Could anyone help me get this working?

[My Google Cloud Platform Firewall rules here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RHTD.png)

Server-side code:

```
require 'socket'

module WebsocketTest
  module_function

  def init
    @server = TCPServer.new('0.0.0.0', 8080)
    @running = false
  end

  def run
    STDERR.puts 'Server is running'
    @running = true

    while @running
      socket = @server.accept
      STDERR.puts 'Incoming Request'
      http_request = ''
      while (line = socket.gets) && (line != "\r\n")
        http_request += line
      end
      STDERR.puts http_request
      socket.close
    end
  end
end

WebsocketTest.init
WebsocketTest.run
```

Client-side code:

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new('External IP of the VM', 8080)
s.send('Hello World!', 0)
s.close
```

Error message:

```
client.rb:3:in `initialize': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) for "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port 8080 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out, it may sound stupid...I was using Active Cloud Shell inside the GCP webpage and connected to my project, which seems is a temporary environment. Later I connect to the instance via SSH in the "VM instance" panel, get the code in OP running and everything goes fine.